# Querying XML Datastores with XPath-5

Tags: xpath

Assume that you have been provided the fragment of XML, shown below. Your task is to write the XPath selector for picking up the shelf of the movie named 'Transformers'.

```html
<collection shelf="Classics">
<movie title="The Enemy" shelf="A">
   <type>War, Thriller</type>
   <format>DVD</format>
   <year>2001</year>
   <rating>PG</rating>
   <popularity>10</popularity>
   <description>Talk about a war</description>
</movie>
<movie title="Transformers" shelf="B">
   <type>Science Fiction</type>
   <format>DVD</format>
   <year>1980</year>
   <rating>R</rating>
   <popularity>7</popularity>
   <description>Science Fiction</description>
</movie>
   <movie title="Trigun" shelf="B">
   <type>Action</type>
   <format>DVD</format>
   <episodes>4</episodes>
   <rating>PG</rating>
   <popularity>10</popularity>
   <description>Quite a bit of action!</description>
</movie>
<movie title="Ishtar" shelf="A">
   <type>Comedy</type>
   <format>VHS</format>
   <rating>PG</rating>
   <popularity>2</popularity>
   <description>Boring</description>
</movie>
</collection>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming title has no spare spaces try this

```
//movie[@title='Transformers']/@shelf
```

Comment: task1:Your task is to write the XPath selector to compute the average popularity of movies, correct to 2 places of decimal.

task2:Your task is to write the XPath selector for picking up the name of the movie for which the description contains the substring "bit".

task3:Your task is to write the XPath selector for listing the format of the movies with popularity<8, in the same order as which they occur in the given XML

Comment: please help me out with this.

Comment: Task 2: //movie[contains(./description, 'bit')]/@title

Comment: Task3: //movie[./popularity<8]/format

Comment: Task1: avg(//movie/popularity)

Comment: task 3 isnt working.

Comment: it returns DVD, VHS in my test that seems correct. The second DVD and the last VHS are passing the filter.

Comment: task 1 solution:  require 'rexml/document'
include REXML
xmlText = "" 
while line = gets()
   xmlText += line
end

doc = Document.new xmlText
puts XPath.match(doc,"avg(//movie/popularity)")

Comment: task 3 solution:  
require 'rexml/document'
include REXML

xmlText = "" 

while line = gets()
   xmlText += line
end

doc = Document.new xmlText

puts doc.elements.each(" //movie[./popularity<8]/format")

Comment: i have commented my code.Please have a look at it.

Comment: The xpath is correct, Ruby code not working. Need to create question tagged as Ruby and include your code there.